# リアルタイムでのAD変換方法

Tags: c

PIC16F1827を用いAD変換値で
LEDの点滅速度を変化させようとしています。

以下にコードを示します。
　　　↓

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = ON       // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Memory Code Protection (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset enabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = ON        // Internal/External Switchover (Internal/External Switchover mode is enabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config PLLEN = OFF      // PLL Enable (4x PLL disabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = HI        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), high trip point selected.)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming enabled)

void internal_osc();
void io_int();
void adc_int();
int adc_read();
void wait1(char val);
int adc_tmp;

void main(void){
    internal_osc();
    io_int();
    adc_int();
    while(1){
        adc_tmp = adc_read();
        PORTB = 0x01;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x03;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x07;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x0f;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x00;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x0f;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x00;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x0f;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
    }
}

void internal_osc(void){
    /*
     * SPLLEN=0;4xPLL is disabled
     * IRCF=1101;4MHz
     * SCS=10;Internal oscillator block
     * OSCCON=0b01101010;
     */
    OSCCON = 0x6a;
}
void io_int(void){
    /*
     * RB0=0;LED0
     * RB1=0;LED1
     * RB2=0;LED2
     * RB3=0;LED3
     * RA0=1;AN0
     * TRISA=0b00000001;
     * TRISB=0b00000000;
     * ANSELA=0b00000001;
     * ANSELB=0b00000000;
     */
    TRISA = 0x01;
    TRISB = 0x00;
    ANSELA = 0x01;
    ANSELB = 0x00;
}
void adc_int(void){
    /*
     * CHS=00000;AN0
     * ADON=1;
     * ADFM=1;Right justified
     * ADCS=001;FOSC->1/8;
     * ->4MHz ad_scan 2us
     * ADNREF=0;VREF- is connected to AVSS
     * ADPREF=00;VREF+ is connected to AVDD
     * ADCON0=0b00000001;
     * ADCON1=0b10010000;
     */
    ADCON0 = 0x01;
    ADCON1 = 0x90;
}
int adc_read(void){
    __delay_us(20);
    ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE = 1;
    while(ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE);
    return (ADRESH<<8) + ADRESL;
}
void wait1(char val){
    for(int i=0; i<=val; i++){
        __delay_ms(10);
    }
}
```

このコードではAD変換値を読み取ったら
whileで先頭に戻るまでadc_tmpの値を
変化させることはできないかと思います。

whileループの中で依存せず、
自由にadc_tmpの値を変化させる
方法が思いつきません。

どなたかご教授お願いします。

Comment: 「自由に adc_tmp の値を変化させる」という部分がどういう動作を示しているのかよく分からないのですが、もう少し説明して頂けませんでしょうか。もしそれができたらどのように動作するはずですか？　あるいは、それができないと何ができないですか？

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。


「自由に adc_tmp の値を変化させる」
→void main(void){}に依存せずPIC16F1827でAD変換をさせadc_tmpに格納させます。

もしそれができたらどのように動作するはず‌​ですか？
→処理の場所に限らずLEDの点滅速度を自由に変えられる。

それができないと何が‌​できないですか？
→whileでadc_tmp = adc_read();まで戻らないとLEDの点滅速度が変わらない。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
タイマー割り込みを用い、割り込み中にAD変換をすることで
メインルーチンに依存せずLEDの点滅速度を変化させることができました。
ありがとうございました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = ON       // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Memory Code Protection (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset enabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = ON        // Internal/External Switchover (Internal/External Switchover mode is enabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config PLLEN = OFF      // PLL Enable (4x PLL disabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = HI        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), high trip point selected.)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming enabled)

void internal_osc();
void io_int();
void tmr0_int();
void adc_int();
int adc_read();
void wait1(char val);
char tmr0_cnt;
int adc_tmp;

void main(void){
    internal_osc();
    io_int();
    tmr0_int();
    adc_int();
    while(1){
        PORTB = 0x01;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x03;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x07;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x0f;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x00;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x0f;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x00;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
        PORTB = 0x0f;
        wait1(adc_tmp>>2);
    }
}
void interrupt ISR(void){
    INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;
    TMR0 = 130;
    adc_tmp = adc_read();
}
void internal_osc(void){
    /*
     * SPLLEN=0;4xPLL is disabled
     * IRCF=1101;4MHz
     * SCS=10;Internal oscillator block
     * OSCCON=0b01101010;
     */
    OSCCON = 0x6a;
}
void io_int(void){
    /*
     * RB0=0;LED0
     * RB1=0;LED1
     * RB2=0;LED2
     * RB3=0;LED3
     * RA0=1;AN0
     * TRISA=0b00000001;
     * TRISB=0b00000000;
     * ANSELA=0b00000001;
     * ANSELB=0b00000000;
     */
    TRISA = 0x01;
    TRISB = 0x00;
    ANSELA = 0x01;
    ANSELB = 0x00;
}
void tmr0_int(void){
    /*
     * 1msec interval_timer
     * FOSC->4MHz
     * interval_time=(255-TMR0)*(FOSC/4)*PS;
     * PS=010;Prescaler->1/8
     * TMR0=130
     * OPTION_REG=0b10000010;
     */
    OPTION_REG = 0x82;
    TMR0 = 130;
    INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1;
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
}
void adc_int(void){
    /*
     * CHS=00000;AN0
     * ADON=1;
     * ADFM=1;Right justified
     * ADCS=001;FOSC->1/8;
     * ->4MHz ad_scan 2us
     * ADNREF=0;VREF- is connected to AVSS
     * ADPREF=00;VREF+ is connected to AVDD
     * ADCON0=0b00000001;
     * ADCON1=0b10010000;
     */
    ADCON0 = 0x01;
    ADCON1 = 0x90;
}
int adc_read(void){
    __delay_us(20);
    ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE = 1;
    while(ADCON0bits.GO_nDONE);
    return (ADRESH<<8) + ADRESL;
}
void wait1(char val){
    for(int i=0; i<=val; i++){
        __delay_ms(10);
    }
}
```